# I want to create a ssl certificate for zeppelin server

Tags: ssl, https, apache-zeppelin

I am running a zeppelin server on aws ec2 instance. I want to launch it on https, currently on http and its working fine.
How can I launch my zeppelin server on https.
I followed the steps given on http://carminedimascio.com/2015/06/running-zeppelin-with-ssl/ 
but its still not working.
I have checked the security groups as well.
Please help

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Well , the one point where you can be doing mistake is after generating CSR are you using the same CSR file to request SSL certificate from CA authority or not ? If not, then again generate a new key store with all correct information and then use that keystore to generate CSR . Then important point is to paste the contents of this CSR file when requesting a certificate from CA authority. After then, install your certificates into the keystore. Then provide the path of your keystore in Zeppelin Server configuration. If carefully followed, this will definitely work :) .

Comment: where do I paste the content of the csr

Comment: are you buying a paid ssl certificate or just want to install  a  self-signed certificate ? If you are buying a paid certificate , then certifcate selling website always asks you for CSR . There you paste or submit your CSR file to generate the certificate.

Comment: hey, i am installing a self signed certificate

Comment: then ignore CSR step and just install certificates into the keystore . You are done.

Comment: this site can’t provide a secure connectio

Comment: are you getting red sign in the browser pad lock icon ?

Comment: no. i am not getting anything.its only working on http

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm running into the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The steps at http://carminedimascio.com/2015/06/running-zeppelin-with-ssl/ actually work. Provided an export password is set, which is different from the keystore password set in a previous step.

To give an idea,

mkdir ~/.mykeystore

cd ~/.mykeystore

openssl genrsa -des3 -out jetty.key 2048

passwd abcd

openssl req -new -x509 -key jetty.key -out jetty.crt

Enter pass phrase for jetty.key: abcd

keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file jetty.crt -trustcacerts

Enter keystore password ABCDEF

Re-enter new password:  ABCDEF

Trust this certificate? [no]: yes

Certificate was added to keystore

openssl req -new -key jetty.key -out jetty.csr

Enter pass phrase for jetty.key: abcd

openssl pkcs12 -inkey jetty.key -in jetty.crt -export -out jetty.pkcs12

Enter pass phrase for jetty.key: abcd

Enter Export Password: BCDEFG

Verifying - Enter Export Password: BCDEFG

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore

Enter destination keystore password:  ABCDEF

 Enter source keystore password: BCDEFG

Entry for alias 1 successfully imported.

Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled

(export passwd then becomes the source passwd in this last step)

Also, paths to the keystore in zeppelin-site.xml must be of the form,
/home/to/something/keystore (it's not the just the path it requires but the path with the keystore filename included).